# what is the exact difference between return a class and a object

Tags: python

Please guide to an explain of the difference between 
object = class()
and 
var = class method returning a class:

```
class Countsome(object):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, x, y):
        self = cls()
        sum = self.add2(x, y)
        print sum
        return cls

    def add2(self, x, y):
        sum = x+y
        return sum

xyz = Countsome.get(5, 9)
```

==========================================

```
class CountSome(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add2(self, x, y):
        sum = x+y
        print sum


xyz = CountSome()
xyz.add2(5, 9)
```

Looking to understand where I should use one, I am just printing the sum so not returning, so please assume I am asking this question for these kind of tasks(where returning results like sum is not important).
And looking for answers like, which one would be efficient, when.

What are the benefits of each and scenarios best suited for each. Guide to a source if possible

Comment: comments with -ve votes are welcomed

Comment: What do you mean by return a class? in your first code block you use `classmethod` where in the second just a regular instance method which doesn't have to be an instance method

Answer (score 0):

You kinda get it wrong. **classmethod** should be use when you need to perform action that doesn't need an instance but does need the `cls` object:

> A class method receives the class as implicit first argument, just like an instance method receives the instance.

For example, if you have a `COUNTER` object in your class which counts how many instances were instantiated.

The second code is actually using **staticmethod**; that is a method defined in a class but don't need access to any class / instance attributes. staticmethod can be defined outside of a class but resides in it for convenience

Comment: I dont see anything **staticmethod** in the question

Comment: `add2` can be declared as **staticmethod** since it doesn't do anything related with the object; actually if you are using pycharm it will indicate that